# Using -webkit-overflow-scrolling in iOS5 (Sticky headers and footers

Tags: webkit, overflow, ios5

in iOS5 (as we all know by now), Apple has introduced -webkit-overflow-scrolling which allows for native scrolling. My question is when applying sticky footer and headers - if you scroll up to the top/bottom part of the page - it will let you "bounce" outside the top header or footer.

Is there anyway to just have the INNER CONTENT bounce or be elastic and not the entire window? I'd like the header and footer to stay at the top not be able to see the grey are behind a "webapp".

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently a known issue with native div scrolling on iOS 5.  More information and a partial fix [here](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2011/10/14/a-fix-for-ios5-overflow-scrolling-scrollfix-js/).

Apple is supposedly aware of the [problem](https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix) and I guess we are waiting on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately haven't been able to find a way to do this while using -webkit-overflow-scrolling (as opposed to handling touchmove events where I'd just use the preventDefault method of the event object).